# Evaluating jFileChooser options

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm working with a program that opens a jDialog from jMenu, I need to evaluate the option that the users choose (Open, Cancel or Exit) in order to proceed in different ways.

```
int result;//
    result = jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(this);

    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.out.println(jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile().getName());
        System.out.println(jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        ...
        } 
    else if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        ...
    }
```

The problem is that everytime I need to evaluate result, showOpenDialog() opens again the dialog.
Is there any other way to get options without oppening dialog?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you mean you have to run this code block again and again just for evaluating result that is already choosed. If this is the truth, and you can't split the showOpenDialog() thing with if...else... thing, you can define a varible belong to your class, which name can be "IsChoosed"(boolean), and then doing like this:

```
    if(IsChoosed == false) {
        result = jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(this);
        IsChoosed = true;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but because I have to run it in so many different functions which obligates me to use a global variable, I decided to ask for another way.
Thanks for the answer